# How to delete unwanted BlackBerry contact list

Tags: sync, gmail, blackberry, gmail-contacts

I have a BlackBerry Curve 9300 setup which was previously setup to sync my gmail and I wanted to add contacts as well.  I followed [this tutorial](http://helpblog.blackberry.com/2010/11/gmail-sync-blackberry/), I have 6.0 Bundle 3106 (v6.0.0.723, Platform 6.6.0.248).

Now when I open Contacts from the home screen, I have *two* contact lists, both with my e-mail address as the name.  A lot of the contacts are duplicated between the lists.

- I've tried rebooting the phone (and pulling the battery out)
- I've tried disabling / reenabling sync again
- I've confirmed the contacts on my Gmail account are accurate.

Is it possible to remove the duplicate list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to track down a [related question](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Pearl/HELP-Remove-Gmail-Contact-List-from-Blackberry-Pearl-9105/td-p/1361287) on the BlackBerry forums which helped me solve the problem.  Here are the steps:

1. Open Contacts app
2. Click BlackBerry button
3. Type "RSET" (there's no dialog box, just type it straight on the screen)
4. Confirm that you want to delete the list which is not configured for wireless sync.  This will delete the entire contact list and it's contacts
5. Confirm you wan to resynchronize the list is is configured for wireless sync.  This will delete and redownload all your contacts.